# Directive referencing its own id

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui-dialog

I've used a directive to utilize jqueryUI dialogs.

```
app.directive('popUp', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            myId: '@',
            onCancel: '&'
        },
        template: 
            '<div id="{{myId}}">
                <button ng-click="onCancel()">...</button>  
                ...
            </div>' 
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.closeDialog = function() {
                $("#" + id).dialog('close');
            }
            // question 1: how to reference id of this directive (self)?
            // question 2: should it be here, in compile, or in directive controller?
            // question 3: 'ng-click=closeDialog()' missing when popup element inspected in firebug/dev tool
            // question 4: is there a way to avoid jquery like selector $("#" + id) to reference this element?
        }               
    };
});
```

And this is the html:

```
<pop-up my-id="success" on-cancel="closeDialog()"> ... </pop-up>
```

If I declare an external controller and `closeDialog` function attached to its `$scope`, this works fine, like this:

```
app.controller('DialogCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.closeDialog = function(id) {
        $("#" + id).dialog('close');
    };

});
```

html

```
<div ng-controller="DialogCtrl">
    <pop-up my-id="success" on-cancel="closeDialog('success')"> ... </pop-up> 
</div>
```

But what I want to avoid is redundancy of the id. So I want the directive to have its own close function. If you also have answers on the other questions above, it is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially what you want. There's no need to use `$` selectors and ids to find your dialog since `element` in the link function will give you a reference to the element that the directive is applied to.

Define the `closeDialog` function on the directive's scope and you can reference it from the directive's template. Each instance of the directive will have its own close function.

```
app.directive('popUp', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            myId: '@'
        },
        template: 
            '<div id="{{myId}}">
                <button ng-click="closeDialog()">...</button>
                ...
            </div>' 
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // initialise dialog
            element.dialog();

            // the template's ng-click will call this
            scope.closeDialog = function() {
                element.dialog('close');
            };
        }               
    };
});
```

No need for an on-cancel attribute now.

```
<pop-up my-id="success"></pop-up>
```

Comment: Will `element.dialog()` invoke the pop-up?

Comment: that's just calling the simplest jQueryUI dialog API. Substitute it with what you need.

Comment: How do I invoke `element.dialog()` outside this directive? Like in an external controller?

Comment: I thought you already had that sorted? How are you opening your dialogs now?